# Upgrading Grails to 1.3.7, need troubleshooting assistance

Tags: grails, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a Grails application from 1.0.3 to 1.3.7.

I've created a Grails 1.3.7 project, and have done my best to copy over the old classes and other files the new project. Of course, something has gone wrong:

```
$ grails run-app
<--snip-->
Running Grails application..
2011-10-20 13:37:47,195 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:788)
    ... 24 more
```

If you look through this stack trace, you will find no references to the code of my application, which is making it hard for me to track down.

I need some suggestions of what I could check that could this error. Here is my `applicationContext.xml` which seems unlikely to be the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
  <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
    <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
  <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
    <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
    <constructor-arg>
      <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
    </constructor-arg>
  <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean">
    <property name="grailsResourceHolder" ref="grailsResourceHolder" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="grailsResourceHolder" scope="prototype" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsResourceHolder">
    <property name="resources">
      <value>classpath*:**/grails-app/**/*.groovy</value>
    </property>
  </bean>    

  <bean id="characterEncodingFilter"
  class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
    <property name="encoding">
      <value>utf-8</value>
    </property>
  </bean>       
</beans>
```

Help is greatly appreciated, and just let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Maybe save this headache till next month when Grails 2.0 comes out?  That way you are not out of date again so quickly.

Comment: Haha, nice thought. But at my company, having permission to move up to 1.3.7 is as cutting-edge as we can reasonably hope for.

Answer (score 1):

From the notes I took when I upgraded a project from Grails 1.0.3 to 1.3.7 (not all these steps may be necessary):

- Make sure your project source are in packages (i.e., "com.companyname.projectname", not in the default package)
- Make sure plugin source are also in packages (i.e., "org.grails.pluginname", not in the default package)
- Remove hibernate.jar from the project\lib directory (hibernate is now a plugin)
- With GRAILS_HOME set to the new version, create a dummy project and copy the fresh BuildConfig.groovy into the project to be upgraded
- Run "grails upgrade" and answer "y" to the prompts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in stacktrace.log, it will possibly give you a better understanding of the actual problem.
Also try "grails clean" and "grails compile" before "grails run-app" to see if it's a problem with old garbage.

Comment: `stacktrace.log` didn't give me any real insight, it looked like the same stacktrace. And I have been doing `grails clean` every time. So thanks for the suggestions, but no success.